# scrollbar inside iframe not working - zindex issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

See http://plnkr.co/edit/hPyYUCBYvWguyNniCexk?p=preview for a basic example (the original solution is much more complex). The problem is that I cannot scroll the div inside iframe because main page has another div on top. Is there a nice way to fix this (ideally without handling javascript events)?

```
<html>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:100;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.01);">
</div>
<iframe src="main.html" style="width:100%;height:100%">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>


<html>
<body>
<div style="overflow:auto;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:2000px;width:2000px">
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:green;z-index:2;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add `pointer-events: none;` style to your div element.